# How Can I Trigger An Action 30 Days After A Date?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, cron

I have a requirement to update a field if a payment date is 30 days late.
Is it possible to trigger an action to occur 30 days after the payment date?

The process is likely to restart in-between those times so it can't be in-memory and it can't be a relative date.

I can create an endpoint like `/api/paymentdates` so that it could be called from something else like cron.
However, there are likely to be a over a million items at some point in the future, each with its own date.

Is there an effective way to trigger a task like this or is the only option to run a task every morning and query the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a Queue Triggered Function (Storage Queue or Service Bus Queue). Basically what you will do is put a message in a queue and keep it invisible for 30 days (it is called initial visibility timeout in storage queue and scheduled message in service bus queue).

The message will only appear in the queue after its invisibility expires and the Function will be triggered at that time. Once the Function is triggered, you can do whatever processing you want to do on that message.

You may find following links useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus